# #pragma omp flush to make exchange data among threads

Tags: c, openmp

Hi writing a very simple example on how to use omp flush to exchange data, in a producer-> consumer way,among threads I have found a funny behavior.

```
int a=-1;
int flag=1;
int count=0;
#pragma omp parallel  num_threads(2)
{ 
    int TID;
    TID=omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp sections 
    {

#pragma omp section /////////// Producer
        {

            for(int i=0; i<9;i++)
            {
                a=i;
#pragma omp flush(a)
                flag=1;
                printf("Producer a: %d  flag:%d  TID %d \n",a,flag,TID);

                while(flag)
                {

#pragma omp flush(flag)

                }

            }
            flag=2;
#pragma omp flush(flag)

        } // end producer

#pragma omp section  /////////// Consumer
        {
            while(1) {
                count++;

                flag=0;
                while(!flag)
                {
#pragma omp flush(flag)
                }
#pragma omp flush(a)
                printf("Consumer a: %d  Flag: %d  count %d TID %d \n",a,flag,count,TID);
                if (flag==2) break; // no more data

            } // end while(1)
        }// end consumer
    }// end sections
```

Using this very simple code will produce an erroneous output:
Producer a: 0  flag:1  TID 0
Producer a: 1  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 1  Flag: 1  count 1 TID 1
Producer a: 2  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 2  Flag: 1  count 2 TID 1
Producer a: 3  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 3  Flag: 1  count 3 TID 1
Producer a: 4  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 4  Flag: 1  count 4 TID 1
Producer a: 5  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 5  Flag: 1  count 5 TID 1
Producer a: 6  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 6  Flag: 1  count 6 TID 1
Producer a: 7  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 7  Flag: 1  count 7 TID 1
Producer a: 8  flag:1  TID 0
Consumer a: 8  Flag: 1  count 8 TID 1
Consumer a: 8  Flag: 2  count 9 TID 1

The error is that the first datum produced a=0 is ignored by the consumer.
If I simply invert the order of the sections, letting the producer be thread 1 then everything is ok..... 
Producer a: 0  flag:1  TID 1
Consumer a: 0  Flag: 1  count 1 TID 0
Producer a: 1  flag:1  TID 1
Consumer a: 1  Flag: 1  count 2 TID 0
....
Whats my mistake ?

.....
After the interesting discussion with Ejd (thanks) the code was edited to:

```
int a=-1;
int flag=0;
int count=0;
#pragma omp parallel  num_threads(2)
{ 
int TID;
TID=omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp sections 
{
#pragma omp section  /////////// Consumer
    {

        while(1) {
            count++;
            if (flag) printf("Consumer a: %d  Flag: %d  count %d TID %d \n",a,flag,count,TID);
            flag=0;
            while(!flag)
            {
#pragma omp flush(flag)
            }
            if (flag==2) break; // no more data

        } // end while(1)
    }// end consumer

#pragma omp section /////////// Producer
    {
        for(int i=0; i<9;i++)
        {
            a=i;
            printf("Producer a: %d  flag:%d  TID %d \n",a,flag,TID);
            flag=1;
            while(flag)
            {
#pragma omp flush(flag,a)
            }

        }
        flag=2;
#pragma omp flush(flag)

    } // end producer


}// end sections
```

That now works nicely. Thanks !

Comment: little error.... first line of last output was starting with: Producer a: 0  flag:1  TID 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately using flush is a lot more complicated than it seems at first glance.  Even the experts in OpenMP have trouble trying to use it correctly.  Part of the problem, is that flush with a list is badly defined.  Basically it is allowed to move, so if you have a sequence of the form:

```
a = ...
#pragma omp flush(a)
b = ...
#pragma omp flush(b)
```

the flush(a) has to be after the setting of a, but could be moved after the set and flush(b).  It just has to occur before the next use of a.

In any case, the best way to do what you want, is to use flush **without** a list and do the flush after every set of a variable that you are interested in and do a flush before the read of every variable you are interested in.

The other problem is that you are not handing off correctly.  You can't set the flag in the consumer for the producer to generate another number until after the consumer has actually consumed the value produced.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer....tried immediately to take out all the list from flush..... and added one before read  problem remains if I mantain that order of sections.....

Comment: Tryed also to put the flag=0.... flush after the printf . This solves the problem IF the consumer is thread 1 but the problem remains (even worse) if consumer is thread 0..... thanks again....

Comment: I was able to slghtly modify your code and get it working.  Since this is all too often a homework problem, I don't really want to just post the code.  Take a close look at your "handshake" with flag and work it through.  The problem is now with your code.  If you don't see it after looking, post your new code and I will try and give you a further hint.

Comment: Well I have a code that work. But there is still a dependancy on the order of the sections. Seems like that first sections starts before the others .... is that corect ? Regarding the "home work"..... in that class I'm supposed to be the teacher. I'm a physicist trying to teach IT to physics students..... maybe I will leave it as a home work ;-).

Comment: It is hard to tell when the first section is started.  Usually it is run by the master thread and so it can be the first section started or it could be started after all of the other threads start.  If your handshake is correct, it shouldn't matter which section is the producer or the consumer and it shouldn't matter which section runs first.

Comment: Done ! with a little modification now the code works with any order of the sections ! Thanks a lot for the interesting discussion !